# convert string to double not working?

Tags: c#, string, double

I'd like to convert a `string` to a `double`. I know, it has been asked before, but let me finish it! :)
So I read the string in from a USB port (Arduino experiment), and I'd like to add that value to a list of doubles. The values are coming in continuously. 
The problem is, when I try to convert the string to double it gives an error message that says: "*The format of the incoming character chain is wrong*" or something like this. I get this error message with both the parse and convert command.
What should I do?

Here's the part of the code that supposed to do the job:

```
namespace voltmeres{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<double> lista = new List<double>();
    int i;
    double f;
    string POT;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        lista.Capacity = 100;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            POT =serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                textBox1.Text = POT.ToString();
        }
        f = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        lista.Add(f);
        i++;
        if (i == lista.Capacity)
        {
            lista.Capacity=lista.Capacity + 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint and tell us what string you have. Then do this in the Watch of your Visual Studio: `(1.1).ToString()` and paste it here.

Comment: Well, what does the string look like? `Convert.ToDouble` works just fine, but if you give it invalid characters it will of course complain. So what are you feeding it? Can you show the string value you're trying to convert?

Comment: Please provide us the exact error message. What does the input string look like?

Comment: The code isn't your problem.  Its the input string.  And the error message even tells you so!  Look at what input data you're getting.

Comment: Is the textbox even showing the data correctly? I was wondering if it could be the SerialPort.ReadExisting method throwing the exception. You don't need to do ToString() on a string object btw.

Comment: This question raises so many more questions. How is the double being transferred from the Arduino? Is it actually a string representation? If not, you'll need to write your own conversion function. If it is, are you reading from the port before all the data has transferred? You may need to buffer until you're sure you've received everything.

Comment: I affraid I can't provide you with the exact error message, because it's in Hungarian and I can't translate it exactly.
Well, the textbox shows the values like this: 3.42 . I suppose it's showing the data correctly.

I copy the arduino reads the values with analogRead.

Comment: The fact that the error message is in Hungarian may be important. :)  While in the US, we consider `pi` to be `3.14159`, most European countries write it as `3,14159`.  The decimal separator is Localized depending on the computer settings.  Look into encodings, and see if other representations will convert better?

Comment: Well I played a bit with conversions. And If I convert a double to string and write out in a textbox, it writes not with a . but with a , . Like this: 3,14 .

Comment: Translated the error message again hope it's correct now: "the format of the input string is incorrect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like it's a number formatting issue. Try the following:

```
f = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Okay translated it again. Hope it's correct: "the format of the input string is incorrect" .

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solved the problem. I also tried the same... :(

Comment: You were close!
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text,NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f);
That solved it ! :D
Thank you and for everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            POT = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            textBox1.Text = POT.ToString();
        }

        if (! double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out f)) return;

        f = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        lista.Add(f);
        i++;
        if (i == lista.Capacity)
        {
            lista.Capacity = lista.Capacity + 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works, but it asks for a out value. 
What is that?

Comment: double.TryParse(string,out doubleParameter) return bool value [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx). It is check whether input string value parsable into double or not... if yes then follow method or go back(return). I edited code now it should be `out f`.

Comment: **if (! double.TryParse(textBox1.Text System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `double.TryParse` instead. It will parse if it is a double, else it will not throw an exception.

```
if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text,outf))
{
   lista.Add(f);
    i++;
    if (i == lista.Capacity)
    {
        lista.Capacity=lista.Capacity + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is not the exception but the string not being parsed. Using another method that won't parse the string as well ain't that helpful.

Comment: do you know of a method that will parse a string that cannot be parsed? the problem is how to properly handle the situation. and this is the best possible way

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Sorry, but your solution does not solve the problem, it hides it. The mistake the OP made was to not take the number formatting into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers don't work, try 'String.valueOf(your double);' This should do the trick if your double is correct.

Another suggestion : depending on the double you have, for instance if it is a really long double, you may want to format the value before or after the conversion to take only a few digits.